# How to "dependsOn" all copies of a resource?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

How can I set up a dependsOn to depend on all copies of a certain resource? Hypothetically, I deploy 0..N number of websites and I need them all to complete before I deploy my traffic manager because the TM needs resource IDs.

Currently I'm only deploying 2 and so I'm just enumerating two items in the dependsOn array, but if I decide I want to deploy more copies (as determined by 
 [variables('tdfConfiguration')] array), it would be nice for dependsOn to dynamically figure this out.

```
  "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "name": "[concat(resourceGroup().name, '-', variables('tdfConfiguration')[0]['roleName'], '-tmprofile')]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat(resourceGroup().Name, '-', variables('tdfConfiguration')[0]['roleName'], '-website')]",
    "[concat(resourceGroup().Name, '-', variables('tdfConfiguration')[1]['roleName'], '-website')]"
  ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fairly easy, use copy name. suppose you have a resource like so:

```
"name": xxx,
"type": zzz,
...
"copy": {
    "name": "myCopy",
    "count": 0..N
}
```

you can use the followin dependsOn to depend on all copies:

```
"dependsOn": [ "myCopy" ]
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple#depend-on-resources-in-a-loop